# modify rendering of \citet*

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib

I would like to change the rendering of `\citet*` using smaller font size and a certain color.

The MWE below works for the unstarred version of `\citet` and produces

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{color}

\let\oldcitet=\citet
\renewcommand{\citet}[1]{{\footnotesize\textcolor[rgb]{.8, .1, .4}{\oldcitet{#1}}}}

\begin{filecontents}{refs.bib}
@book{ref,
title = {title},
author = {john and abi and fein},
location = {here},
publisher = {publisher},
year = {2017},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\citet{ref}

\citet*{ref}

\bibliography{refs.bib}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\end{document}
```

The redefinition of `\citet` breaks that of its starred version. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: It does not only break the starred version but also the optional argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to accommodate the starred version in your setup, you need to condition on the usage of `*` using something like:

```
\let\oldcitet=\citet
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\citet}{\@ifstar\newcitetstar\newcitet}
\newcommand{\newcitet}[1]{{\footnotesize\textcolor[rgb]{.8, .1, .4}{\oldcitet{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\newcitetstar}[1]{{\footnotesize\textcolor[rgb]{.8, .1, .4}{\oldcitet*{#1}}}}
\makeatother
```

[image]

There are easier ways to negotiate other options as well, like optional arguments (for example). For a more general approach I'd consider [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse).